# Deploy Cloud Service on ARM VNET

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-cloud-services

is it possible to deploy a CloudService (created from preview portal) to a ARM-VNet.

This is my conf file:

```
<NetworkConfiguration>
  <VirtualNetworkSite name="my-network" />
  <AddressAssignments>
    <InstanceAddress roleName="webrole">
      <Subnets>
        <Subnet name="Subnet-1" />
      </Subnets>
    </InstanceAddress>
  </AddressAssignments>
</NetworkConfiguration>
```

The VNet does exist but when I try to deploy the service I got the following error:

```
statusCode:BadRequest
serviceRequestId:southcentralus:c1dafc51-0cc8-4208-b725-9d2b069f2c24
statusMessage:{"error":    {"code":"DeploymentSlotUpdateOperationFailed","message":"The update deployment operation failed for the domain '....' in the deployment slot 'staging' with the name 'test': 'The virtual network my-network does not exist.'."}}
```

I was looking at this post: [Azure - Virtual Network does not exist when deploy to Cloud Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356964/azure-virtual-network-does-not-exist-when-deploy-to-cloud-service)

...and and I tried getting the VNet configuration using the powershell console but the command returns the configuration of the classic VNets.

Is there anyway I get the configuration of the ARM-VNets?
Is it possible to deploy the cloudService to the ARM-VNet or it has to be a classic VNet.

Thanks

Comment: It is not possible to deploy the Cloud Service to the ARM-VNet. But, you can deploy the Cloud Service to a classic VNet, and then connect that classic VNet to the ARM-VNet. See [this article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-networks-arm-asm-s2s-howto/)